# Microsoft Graph (5.15) - Get Message By ID

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I am creating a service to read an email by it's ID.  Currenty, everything is geared towards "Me" or "User[""].  But, I just need to retrieve an email by it's ID.  This was available in EWS (On-premise Exchange server).  I am using .NET 6 by the way.

As mentioned in the question, at the time of processing, I only have access to the ID.

Comment: You also need to know the user's id or UPN to be able to read the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do that as long as your know the SMTP address of the mailbox, e.g.:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.demo/messages/AQMkAGU2ZWM5ZTQwLTk0MjMtNDY3NS1iZWI5LWQ4NTA0MDhmM2U0OQBGAAADXoF1TwA_FUmwZZ8q6pLnwgcAx88jBMd79kWF6Ikt1v97rAAAAgEMAAAASnzoXtGrJ0yeIKo8v6gosQAGdvQMUwAAAA==
```

See [Get Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) on MSDN.